# Call a method with two leading underscores from another file - Python

Tags: python

I have two files: main.py and legacy.py; they are located in the same folder.

legacy.py looks like this:

```
def __check():
    ...
    return True if ... else False
```

I need to call `__check` from main.py but it doesn't work. I've tried to do this:

```
from folder import legacy

def main():
    print(legacy.__check())
```

I always receive an error like this one:

> AttributeError: module 'folder.legacy' has no attribute '__check'

Comment: Do you have a `__init__.py` in your folder? If `__init__.py` exists then try `import legacy` instead of `from folder import legacy` in your `main.py`. Refer to [document](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages).

Comment: In general, names that start with `__` but don't also have a `__` at the end are being marked as private in Python.  If the name is defined inside of a class, the name is "mangled" to include the classname.   Whoever wrote this code doesn't want you to import that variable.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! I have learned something from your answers :)

Comment: Something else is going on. Name-mangling only applies to class attributes, not module attributes.

Comment: @chepner I suspect the first comment is correct, there is a subpackage named `legacy` within `folder` which has no such method in its `__init__.py`, and the OP really needs `folder.legacy.legacy`

Answer (score -2):

As mentioned in earlier comments, the leading double underscore is a big clue that you shouldn't be calling this method directly.
However there can be some reasons that this may be necessary, such as for testing, or for working with legacy code.

So, please understand the implications of accessing private variables, but you can do this as described here: https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/python-name-mangling-and-how-to-use-underscores-e67b529f744f

The class name gets mangled in, so you should be able to access the method as:

```
legacy._legacy__check()
```